# DBLCDTempBlack only for some letters in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uilabel

I am uising [this](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html) code for marquee effect. i want digital clock like font so i gave font as

```
 UIFont *lcdFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:60.0]; 
 self.font = lcdFont ;
```

But i am getting this font only for some random characters.I am using only uppercase letters. I want i for all the characters in  UILabel.
Why is it happening so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing wrong with your code -- that font only has certain characters in it. (Why? Who knows.) For those it's missing, the OS automatically falls back to another font.

If you want to draw LCD-looking text using a broader character set, you'll need to find such a font elsewhere and bundle it in your app.